# What is correct syntax for a mapbox setFilter expression when feature property is a boolean

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

myFeatureProperty is is either true or false
I want the filter to be true if it's value is true
I tried this and I get an "emit validation error" (mapbox error doesn't say what is invalid):

`let filter = ['==', ['get',"myFeatureProperty"],true, true, false]`

Any idea why I get this error?  I can't find any examples of this simple task. What is the proper expression syntax for mapbox-gl-js latest version?

Thanks,
Donnie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your property contains actual boolean values, you can use them directly as the filter:

`filter = ['get', 'myFeatureProperty']`

If you really wanted to compare them explicitly to `true` and `false` it would be like this:

`filter = ['==', ['get', 'myFeatureProperty'], true]`

Comment: Thanks Steve! Simple fix!  I get it now. It didn't click that "get" would return true by itself.

Comment: How can I reset the filter to show everything does not matter if true or false?